# Can I catch an event when application is uninstalled in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need to send a notice to my server when the application is uninstalled. Is there a way to catch an event when a user uninstalls the app?

Comment: as far as i know, no.

Answer (score 4):

If you use firebase, you can use the 'app_remove' event listener. You can listen to it using firebase functions : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can there are many packages available to track uninstallation.

1.[**WEBENGAGE**](https://docs.webengage.com/docs) (It's not free)

- You will be able to segment your users and engage with them in a
  contextual and personalized manner through various channels such as
  Push, In-app, SMS, On-site (Notifications, Survey, Feedback), Web
  Push and Email.
- This will give you proper help you to track your users and help 
  you take proper action to improve your growth.

2.[**CLEVERTAP**](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/react-native)

- It enables you to integrate app analytics and marketing

3.[**APPSFLYER**](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/react-native-appsflyer) (30 days free trial)

- it is the world's leading mobile attribution & marketing analytics platform, helping app marketers around the world make better decisions.

Note: All the above platforms provide unintsall tracking, So choose according to your usecase.

4.**Without Third Party Library**

This you can achieve through Push Notification. You can save device token with user email_id. So now you can send notification to all the registered devices and can filter out those devices along with their email_ids which were failed to receive notification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if the user never allowed notifications at first place?
can we differentiate between app uninstalls and notifications blocked?