# Is there any way to track when the user uninstalled the app with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm looking for a way to monitor the application's uninstall event so that when the uninstall occurs I generate a specific action

Comment: What action are you trying to generate? You can track uninstalls with google-analytics but to actually perform an action once it is uninstalled sounds pretty unlikely.

Comment: The intention is as soon as the app is uninstalled I will send a request to remove the user token from the database, because whenever the app is installed/reinstalled the app generates a new token

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51157612/3832047 but it looks like a bit of a dead end unless you are able to pass parameters to that app_remove event.

Comment: were you able to accomplish this?